# Tensorflow1 DropoutWrapper to Tensorflow2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

How to rewrite this one in tensorflow2? Tried using `tf_upgrade_v2` it failed. Tried also with `tf.keras.layers.Dropout` but had some issues converting `MultiRNNCell` to tensor

```
rnn_cells = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(
            [lstm_cell(size_layer) for _ in range(num_layers)],
            state_is_tuple = False,
        )
drop = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(rnn_cells, output_keep_prob = forget_bias)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I replaced:

```
drop = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(rnn_cells, output_keep_prob = forget_bias)
```

With:

```
drop = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(rnn_cells, output_keep_prob = forget_bias)
```

And it worked

Answer (score -3):

Here's the rewritten code in TensorFlow 2, incorporating key changes and explanations:

**1. Import the necessary layers:**

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTMCell, RNN, Dropout
```

**2. Create the LSTM cells**

```
lstm_cells = [LSTMCell(size_layer) for _ in range(num_layers)]
```

**3. Construct the RNN layer with dropout:**

```
rnn = RNN(
    lstm_cells,
    return_sequences=True,  # Set to True if you need to return all outputs
    return_state=False,    # Set to True if you need to return the final state
)

drop = Dropout(forget_bias)(rnn)  # Apply dropout after the RNN layer
```

Comment: Raises an error I talked about: `Failed to convert elements of <keras.src.layers.rnn.base_rnn.RNN object at 0x15d327610> to Tensor`